# How to allow apostrophe in asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

In my asp.net website I create user with their details, If suppose the surname of the user is 
`Sam's` then when I edit the user the display in the text box is `Sam&#39;s` but in database it is stored as Sam's, and When I just try to update name as Sam's then i get the error below, How should I show the name in the text box   `txt_EditLastName.Text = gvrow.Cells[2].Text;`

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$MainContent$txt_EditLastName="Sam&#39;s").
```

Comment: Is this ASP.net MVC? It doesn't really look like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this error because Visual Studio 2010 added a little bit of security. To work around it you need to add `ValidateRequest="false"` to the page directive or add  `<pages validateRequest="false" />` in the `web.config` file. I put it in the wrong spot at first, so make sure you put that in the `<system.web>` area of your `web.config` file.

This link will help. http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/mswinswdev/ms_vbnet_server_error_potentially_dangerous.htm

Comment: +1: Good answer, but to guard yourself you should explain that the above approach does sacrifice some security.

Comment: Yes, you are right. With my site, it didn't matter because it is only people in my company that are using the pages with less security. If @John is ok with his site being a little less secure, then this is a really easy fix.

Comment: But I dont want the text box to display Sam&#39;s it has to display as Sam's

Answer (score 1):

I used a find and replace of ' with `

```
' - Apostrophe
` - Grave Accent
```

The Grave accent looks the same and can be stored in SQL databases without messing them up.
The grave accent is usually found above the Tab button on your keyboard, to the left of the numbers.

Hope this helps.