# C# Potentially Dangerous Error, Apostrophe during Form Submission

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

Please help me understand why this is happening. My Web Application retrieves text that contains Apostrophe from the database to display using a Label in a Web Form. However, it is getting a Potentially Dangerous Error when I submit the Web Form.

I can solve this error by using HttpUtility.HtmlDecode() on the value before I set it to Label.Text

I have been Googling, and I cannot understand the flow that causes this problem.

I understand that Potentially Dangerous Error occurs when submitting potential HTML tags like '', and it also filters some encoded characters like "'"

However, what I cannot understand are:

1. Does the string value automatically HTML encodes when it displays on the Web Form? Because the value from my database is not HTML encoded.
2. Why does decoding it solves the error when my value from the database is not encoded in the first place? If that is the case, should I decode all values from database?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this -> [How to allow apostrophe in asp.net website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139476/how-to-allow-apostrophe-in-asp-net-website)

The main reason this occurs is mostly due to fact that accepting apostrophes without handling it properly could lead to [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) . By Default Microsoft enables a validation that occurs with every request, this occurs even before it reaches the normal page lifecycle,  and checks if there is anything in the form that could potentially lead to SQL Injection or other [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/.NET_Security_Cheat_Sheet) vulnerabilities (In no way I am saying Microsoft protects you from everything, but at least tries to cover the basics and make you aware). By the end it is up to you to disable that functionality (based on my first link) but you should be aware and protect yourself in a proper manner.

On your questions enconding as the name says will take care of the apostrophe as a proper character not a special character that could still be used for a SQL query for instance. And obviously depending on the scenario you might want to decode or encode it again when you present it. If you want to display rich html then you probably need to decode, etc, etc.

Bottom line I think you should go back to my first paragraph and understand when this starts and only then you will be able to understand what would be the right solution for your case as I assume you dont want to risk creating a vulnerable website :)

Comment: Yep, I read that question you posted before, but I still have unanswered questions. I am not allowed to disable the validation due to nature of my work. What I do not understand is the life cycle of this process; particularly the HTML encoding and decoding parts. Am I right to assume that text is automatically HTML encoded when it renders in the Web Form since the error I encountered quoted &#38;? Why does HTML decoding the text solves my problem? The text in question was not HTML encoded before it was saved in the database. Do you not have to encode before you decode?

Comment: @PikaManiac I don't want to say you obviously need to encode it because it depends on the scenario. In this specific scenario however I think you do need to because I am assuming you have an texarea or something where someone is inserting this:" don't ", when you encode this it becomes  "don &#38;?t" which the browser understands and can render as a "don't".

Look at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/b41v18dq/1/